# what if a single figure is too large to be put in one sheet?

Tags: patent-drawings

When drafting an application, what if a single figure is too large to be put in one sheet? Can I just divide the single figure into two or more sheets? and how?
I have searched this question in MPEP, and it states that "[w]here figures on two or more sheets form in effect a single complete figure, the figures on the several sheets shall be so arranged that the complete figure can be assembled without concealing any part of any of the figures appearing on the various sheets."
I just confused about how to do it? Can anybody give me some reference/patent about such situation?

Answer (score 4):

Having a figure that is too large for one sheet (especially with the minimum font sizes and required margins) is fairly common for electronic circuits, sample computer code to implement a function, or detailed flow charts.

There used to be hard copies of drawing guidelines with samples that folks used as a reference for questions like this.  That material still exists if you look hard enough on the USPTO site.  But to make this quick, here is a link to one of my patents.  Figure 7 is a circuit too large for one sheet.  So you have a first image that shows how the subsequent pieces fit together.  Then you show the pieces. Note the dashed lines that indicate seams between sheets.   http://www.google.com/patents/US8829412

Hope this helps. 
Kevin